# Log4j giving ClassCastException about slf4j LoggerContext

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have configured log4j in my Java application and I am getting this

```
exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to 
  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.
```

I already tried after remove `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.2.jar` and `log4j-to-slf4j-2.2.jar` but It didn't work it out.

Comment: This is probably a dependency conflict problem. If you list your current dependencies (direct and transitive), including versions the question is easier to answer.

Comment: what all jars you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this error by following steps:

1. Include slf4j-api.jar,log4j-api.jar,slf4j-log4j.jar

and

2. Use logger of slf4j.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (is the 'standard' way to use a logger):

In your class:

`private final static Logger logger =`  `LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);`

In your methods:

```
if(logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("your log message");
 }
```

And the maven dependencies (pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>       

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: SLF4J was explicitly designed not to need the .isLevelEnabled()-crutch: http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#typical_usage. Also, if you want to use log4j for logging via slf4j, you will need the bridge as well: slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar